# UicollectionView with layout constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

I am using collection view inside view controller.

I am not using auto layout in IB but resizing collection view.

My problem is it proper working in iphone 4s. when i run on iphone 6 is not proper .

Can i use nslayout constraint ? My imageview cell size width 80 and height 90 is fix .

Any solution to work all devices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using autolayout then, Set the autoresizing mask via properties

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can also do it by code :

```
view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |    
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin);
```

### CELL RESIZE

If you want to change cell size of collection view as per device then use following method :

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width/4)-5, (collectionView.frame.size.width/4)-5);
}
```

Here 5 is your padding between cell.

Comment: @user3821147 Welcome anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

You can autoresize your collection view which will work for all the iPhone devices except iphone 4s, so for iPhone 4S you can set its alignment programmatically. Such as

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{
     //get the screen size of device
     screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
        if (screenHeight == 480){
        //Your code e.g
        <collectionView>.frame = CGRectMake((x-axis),(y-axis),width,height);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use nsautolayout constraint how i use ?

Comment: there is no need of NSAutolayout to be used just set the autoresizing of it from IB Inspector and for Iphone 4s set it prgrammatically . The more you will do it programmatically so then you can easily find out the problem.

Comment: if possible can you give me sample ? in my task its not working

Comment: - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    UIImageView *collectionImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    collectionImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[collectionImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    
    return cell;
}

Comment: Set autoresizing mask for iphone 5s and run it if it works properly then write the code in 
 that - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
UIImageView *collectionImageView;
screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
        if (screenHeight == 480){
collectionImageView.frame = GCReactMake(20,25,80,90); 
}
collectionImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100]; 
collectionImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[collectionImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];